how to make the server not hang after activating the lever
when deleting blocks within a radius of 50 blocks minecraft suspends, and I need to play a sound before the deletion and after 120 seconds began to remove blocks
code:
@Override
public void neighborChanged(BlockState blockstate, net.minecraft.world.level.Level world, BlockPos pos, Block neighborBlock, BlockPos fromPos, boolean moving) {
    super.neighborChanged(blockstate, world, pos, neighborBlock, fromPos, moving);
    if (world instanceof ServerLevel serverLevel && serverLevel.hasNeighborSignal(pos)) {
        playSound(serverLevel, pos);


        replaceBlocksInSphere(serverLevel, pos);

        strength = -1f;
        resistance = 3600000f;

    }
}

private void replaceBlocksInSphere(ServerLevel world, BlockPos centerPos) {
    try {
        sleep(12000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    int chunkRadius = (int) Math.ceil((double) RADIUS / 16); // Определяем радиус в чанках
    int chunkX = centerPos.getX() >> 4; // Получаем координаты чанка центра сферы
    int chunkZ = centerPos.getZ() >> 4;

    for (int chunkXOffset = -chunkRadius; chunkXOffset <= chunkRadius; chunkXOffset++) {
        for (int chunkZOffset = -chunkRadius; chunkZOffset <= chunkRadius; chunkZOffset++) {
            int chunkPosX = chunkX + chunkXOffset;
            int chunkPosZ = chunkZ + chunkZOffset;

            for (int y = centerPos.getY() - RADIUS; y <= centerPos.getY() + RADIUS; y++) {
                for (int x = (chunkPosX << 4); x < (chunkPosX << 4) + 16; x++) {
                    for (int z = (chunkPosZ << 4); z < (chunkPosZ << 4) + 16; z++) {
                        BlockPos mutablePos = new BlockPos(x, y, z);
                        if (centerPos.distSqr(mutablePos) <= RADIUS * RADIUS) {
                            world.setBlockAndUpdate(mutablePos, Blocks.AIR.defaultBlockState()); // Просто устанавливаем воздушный блок
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

It is desirable that the server does not hang

You need to clarify. You are using sleep(...) before replacing/removing the blocks? It will make it wait for that duration. Is that not what you want?

sleep() doesn't work + I need the server to not hang

But the use of sleep() will make it hang? So, what do you want it to do, and what do you not want it to do? If you sleep() for 12 seconds, it will "hang" for 12 seconds.

it's 120 seconds. I want the audio to play first and then the 'explosion' to happen afterwards.

Is sleep() your own method? If it is Thread.sleep(), then 12000 means 12 seconds. Regardless, if you just remove sleep(), it won't "hang".

Oh yeah, how to make the block strength change after the sound is played?

I do not know how to change the block strength in Minecraft. That is a separate discussion. Did removing the sleep() fix the issue?

I can't remove sleep because it's thread.sleep and I need the code to wait 120 seconds after activating the sound, and that the server does not freeze (mobs, blocks do not move)

"hangs" in the sense that it blocks the main thread.
